# Computing the gradient using np.gradient for a quantum-mechanical problem

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to compute the ground-state energy associated to a nonlinear Schrödinger equation without the interaction term and with an external potential given by a 1-D harmonic potential. The expression for the energy involves the square of the absolute value of the gradient of the wave-function and that's where I got stuck.

After doing some research on the internet, I found (at least, I believe) that np.gradient could do the job. However, for my current problem, it hasn't shown any in the sense that when I plot its contribution it returns me a constant function equal to zero. Thus, I think I am doing something wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt        
import numpy as np   
import h5py as h5    
from scipy import integrate

data = h5.File('groundstate.h5', 'r')   
phireal = data['3']['phireal']   
phiimag = data['3']['phiimag']   
lattice = data['3']['y']   
time    = data['3']['t']     

distr = np.power(phireal[:,:],2) + np.power(phiimag[:,:],2)

egradi = np.gradient(phiimag, axis = 0)   
egradr = np.gradient(phireal, axis = 0)   
V = (1/2) * np.power(lattice,2)

intergy = (1/2) * np.power(egradr,2) + V * distr   
energy = integrate.simps(intergy, lattice, 0.1171875)   

fig = plt.figure()   
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)   
ax.plot(time, energy)   
plt.ylabel('E')   
plt.xlabel('t')   

ax.set_ylim(0, 3)   
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)    

plt.show()
```

The data stored in the file groundstate.h5 basically refers to the complex and real parts of the wave-function obtained evolving in imaginary time.

Here I provide a link for the input h5 file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FPM_sdpfQSOxeEikGuQyO4kfwH88wpcZ

In the plot of the energy, I expect to find for higher values of t (time) the value of 1/2 which is the energy of the ground-state of the 1-D quantum harmonic oscillator. However, I am getting a different value, 1/4 and that's why I believe it is because of the kinetic term, in this case, given by the gradient of the wave-function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fntc.png)

Can someone please tell me if this is the correct way of computing the gradient? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide your input file, or a small example of an input file that reproduces the problem? Also note you have a ' out of place at the end of line 1.

Comment: @KBriggs I have updated the original post and provided a shareable google docs link from where you can get the input file.

Comment: What is the spacing between values of f in your groundstate file? I will debug when I can, but my first thought is that when you call `np.gradient` without specifying `varargs` it assumes that `dy=1`, which may not be the case for your data depending on the unit system you're using.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right! I forgot to specify the value of the spacing. The variable y is defined in the interval (-15.0, 15.0) and my lattice has 256 points. Hence, dy = 30/256 = 0.1171875. In addition, I should have put axis = 1 instead of axis = 0 . I added it to my code and now it is returning what I wanted.

Comment: @KBriggs in case I need to generalize it for two and three dimensions, I mean in case my scalar function now depends on x, y and z, how would I do to compute the gradient? Thanks in advance.